# how to get id select type with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code like here :

```
<select class='form-control' id='name_pipe1' name='name_pipe[]' onchange='check_database()' required><option>-- Choose Pipe Name --</option></select>
<select class='form-control' id='name_pipe2' name='name_pipe[]' onchange='check_database()' required><option>-- Choose Pipe Name --</option></select>
<select class='form-control' id='name_pipe3' name='name_pipe[]' onchange='check_database()' required><option>-- Choose Pipe Name --</option></select>
```

how to get id one by one with javascript to fill my check_database ??

Comment: getElementsByClassName(), then iterate in a for loop and get the id with getAttribute().

Comment: isn't `name='name_pipe[]'` a PHP thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id as a parameter inside the function. For example:

```
<select id='name_pipe1' onchange="check_database('name_pipe1')" required><option>-- Choose Pipe Name --</option></select>
```

Or you might pass the event  inside the function

```
<select id='name_pipe1' onchange='check_database(event)' required><option>-- Choose Pipe Name --</option></select>
```

and then inside your function:

```
check_database(event){ const id = event.target.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the the `select.form-control` then check their id:

```
const my_select_list = document.querySelectorAll("select.form-control");
for (let i = 0; i < my_select_list.length; i++) {
    my_id = my_select_list[i].id;
};
```

Then do what you want with the ids.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the `check_database()` you should have access to the `this` object, which will refer to the current element triggering the function.
So you would be able to do something like `this.id` inside `check_database` to get the Id of the changed select.